# Why PCMan File Manager only partially supports Drag & Drop to browser

Tags: linux, ubuntu, browser, file-management, drag-and-drop

PCMan File Manager is [an extremely fast and lightweight file manager](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) with **Drag & Drop** support.

However, when I try to drag files from it and drop into browser, the most convenient way of uploading to almost any sites nowadays, it is not fully working. I tried on https://gist.github.com/. After I drop into browser, the icon just flies back, and gist is not populated at all. Don't know if it is PCManFM's problem though, as I tried Thunar as well, and it is not working either.

BTW, I tried Drag & Drop from PCManFM to browser in gmail, and it works.

Any ideas?

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial


$ apt-cache policy chromium-browser pcmanfm thunar
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233
  Candidate: 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233
  Version table:
 *** 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
pcmanfm:
  Installed: 1.2.4-1
  Candidate: 1.2.4-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.4-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
thunar:
  Installed: 1.6.10-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.6.10-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.10-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: If DnD is broken, your window manager is likely to be at fault. Try a different one temporarily. (Given that you started with pcmanfm, I'm guessing you use something like i3 or openbox, not the default Unity...)

Comment: Good idea, will try it and report back. My current is `fluxbox`. BTW, further test showed that DnD from PCManFM to browser works for gmail. Strange.

Comment: @DavidPostill (and all that want to close it), alright, I've changed it from "software shopping" to a **technical question**.

Comment: @user1686 Actually, I don't see *how* it could be the window manager. DnD works by having one window provide a list of proposed data formats and the receiving window choose one... and they're not as standardized as they should be. For example, it took Firefox a while to support drag-and-drop upload from PCManFM because it didn't offer the type for "list of selected files" that Firefox wanted but other applications accepted it. Then that got fixed, but Audacious Media Player was still a problem because it was weird in how it separated paths within the list but other things were OK with that.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug for PCMan File Manager -- I tried again just now, and  Drag & Drop from PCManFM to https://gist.github.com/ is working.

The current version is (was 1.2.4-1):

```
$ apt-cache policy pcmanfm
pcmanfm:
  Installed: 1.2.5-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.2.5-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.5-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```